# Hibernate is much faster when executing a native query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

The following query is supposed to return about 800 objects. The problem is that hibernate actually executes 800 queries to get them all. It appears to execute one query to get the ids and then executes one query for every object to get the specific data about the object. It takes over 60 seconds for this query to return.

```
List<AUser> result = em.createQuery("FROM AUser where company=:companyId")
.setParameter("companyId",company.getId())
.getResultList();
```

The native query is much faster.

```
List<AUser> result = em.createNativeQuery("select a.* FROM AUser a where a.company=:companyId")
.setParameter("companyId",company.getId())
.getResultList();
```

The above query takes less than one second to return.

Why the difference?

Comment: Can you set showSql to true and see what SQL the HQL is being translated into?

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess here and say you've mapped something in `AUser` to be eagerly fetched. Can you post your mappings? Also, do follow Kaleb's suggestion and post (some of 800) queries as well.

Comment: As Kaleb Brasee suggested in the hibernate.properties set hibernate.show_sql=true to see the SQL output.

Comment: @ChssPly76, you are correct. I took a closer look at the queries and realized that they weren't going to the AUser table (like I had initially thought). They were the result of an eagerly fetched property.

I guess I just need to figure out how to turn eager fetching off for this object for queries like this one which don't need those properties.

Alternatively, perhaps there's a way to get all the joined properties loaded in one query rather than executing one query per object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original issue is caused by property(ies) of `AUser` being eagerly fetched (confirmed by HappyEngineer in comment).

Answering the follow-up question:

Generally, the best approach is to map associations as lazy:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Company company;
```

You can then override fetch mode within your query by using `join fetch`:

```
select user
  from AUser user left join fetch user.company
 where user.company.id = :companyId
```

See [Associations and Joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins) chapter in Hibernate documentation for more details.

Comment: I'm using JPA, so the syntact is a bit different. I had to use "LEFT OUTER JOIN" rather than "left join fetch". It all works now though.

Comment: Your question is tagged as "hibernate" and "hql", though. You may be using JPA **annotations** and `EntityManager` but HQL remains HQL. `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is equivalent to `LEFT JOIN`, it's the `FETCH` part that's important.

Answer (score 2):

This might be n+1 select problem in Hibernate. You shoud follow some best practices to enhance your query performance. There are multiple options like Lazy Loading, Fetch Mode, Fetch Join etc.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html 
n+1 query issue

Regards...